# Which programming languages allow you to define paired-bracket like operators?

Tags: programming-languages, operators

I am looking to create a DSL and I'm looking for a language where you can define your own bracket-style operators for things like the [floor and ceiling functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). I'd rather not go the route of defining my own Antlr parser for a custom syntax.

As a far as I know the only languages I know of that allow you to define custom operators are all binary infix operators.

**tl;dr: Which languages allow for defined paired symbol (like opening bracket/closed bracket) operators?**

---

Also, I don't see how this question can be "too broad" if no one has named a single language that has this and the criteria are very specific and definitely in the programming domain.

Comment: +1. Good Question and an extremely good answer.

Comment: I agree: good question, good answer.  But still, I can't help but think:  suppose you add this customization option to your favorite language.  Wouldn't it be painful to type exotic brackets all the time?

Comment: @comingstorm Well you'd just macro those brackets in, but no, I don't think so: code is read way more often than it's written so you want to optimise for reading not writing. ;) Also, remember this is for a DSL, so it use would be rather limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Fortress is dead, the only languages I know of where something like this would be imaginable are those of FORTH heritage.

In all others that I know of, braces, brackets and parentheses are already heavily used, and can't be overloaded further.

I suggest giving up the quest for such stuff and get comfortable writing

```
floor x
ceiling y
```

or however function application is expressed in the language of your choice.

However, in the article you cite, it is said:  Unicode contains codepoints for these symbols at U+2308–U+230B: ⌈x⌉, ⌊x⌋.

Thus you can at least define this a s operator in a Haskell like language and use like:

```
infix 5 ⌈⌉
(foo ⌈⌉)
```

The best I could come up with is like the following:

```
--- how to make brackets
module Test where

import Prelude.Math

infix 7 `«`
infix 6 `»`

_ « x = Math.ceil x
(»)     = const

x = () «2.345» ()

main _ = println x
```

The output was: 3.0
(This is not actually Haskell, but Frege, a Haskell-like JVM language.)

Note that I used «» instead of ⌈⌉, because I somehow have no font in my IDE that would correctly show the bracket symbols. (This is another reason not to do such.)

The way it works is that with the `infix` directives, we get this parsed as

```
 (»)  ((«) () 2.345)  ()
```

(One could insert any expression in place of the `()`)

Maybe if you ask in the Haskell group, someone finds a better solution.

Comment: I was trying to use an existing notation for ease of auditting by domain experts.

Comment: I understand. But even experts should be able to learn a new notation. To my knowledge, mathematicians are quite flexible in this regard, as most papers define their own notation anyway.

Comment: But still no way of saying `⌈5.5⌉`, even in Haskell?